# String search with asterisk * wildcard character

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am looking to search a string for another shorter string which may contain wildcard characters * which match zero or more characters. For instance, if the main string is "Searching this string for a substring", and search string is "is*ing" should return a match at "is string". What is the algorithm to be used for this kind of search. Most algorithms present do globbing or pattern matching, but they don't do substring search.

Comment: Pattern matching (reg ex) _is_ looking for substrings.

Comment: [Related](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/43637/489)

Comment: You can transform the pattern trivially to a standard regex pattern: just replace every occurance of `*` by `.*`. Things become somewhat hairy if your existing syntax isn't just " `*` = wildcard"  but also includes "except when escaped as `\*`".

Answer (score 1):

Any good substring search algorithm (like KMP) shall serve your purpose.

First search for the substring "is". Then once you found the substring, start searching for the string "ing" in the remaining part of the super-string.

Above technique shall work because you want to find a list of substrings in a particular sequence.